# Encoding python utf-8 splitting

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, split

I've got a variable:

```
age_expectations = dictionary['looking_for']['age']
print type(age_expectations), age_expectations
```

The output is:

```
<type 'unicode'> 22‑35
```

When I'm trying to split it with the dash I've got the following problem:

```
res = age_expectations.split('-')
print res
```

And the output look like:

```
[u'22\u201135']
```

Instead of:

```
["22", "35"]
```

What is the problem? I've tried many encoding and decoding but not really sure to understand how it's work. Does the problem come from the split?

Comment: can describe more details, you are reading from file ?

Comment: Yeah I'm reading from a file, which contain data crawled on a website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unicode` to split the `unicode` like,

```
>>> u_code = u'\u0032\u0032\u2011\u0033\u0035'
>>> print u_code
22‑35
>>> u_code.split('-')
[u'22\u201135']
>>> u_code.split(u'\u2011')
[u'22', u'35']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from your code, the hyphen in your `age_expectations` variable is the unicode U+2011 character, not the standard "-" hyphen. You would have seen it from the start if you had printed the variable's representation instead:

```
>>> uu = u"22\u201135"
>>> print uu
22‑35
>>> print repr(uu)
u'22\u201135'
>>>
```

So you need to either replace the `u"\u2011"` character with a simple hyphen (if you can have any of them in your data) or just simply split the string on `u"\u2011"` (if you're sure you'll *always* get this as delimiter).

Comment: If it's a [non-breaking hyphen](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm) it might even be replaced by an empty string, but that depends on the context.